# Базовая инициализация AssimpNet

Tags: c#, .net, opengl

Нигде не могу найти никаких примеров базовой инициализации AssimpNet.
Работаю в данный момент на C# + OpenGL(OpenTK), но, на сколько я понял, сама графическая библиотека не так важна.
Помогите пройти порог вхождения ссылками, кодом или чем угодно.

Comment: Моей главной ошибкой была не верная сборка AssimpNet. Нужно быть внимательным и компилировать DLL под необходимую версию .Net Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string filename = "...";
bool flipUv = false;
var importer = new AssimpContext();

if (!importer.IsImportFormatSupported(Path.GetExtension(filename)))
{
    throw ...;
}

var postProcessFlags = PostProcessSteps.GenerateSmoothNormals | PostProcessSteps.CalculateTangentSpace;

if (flipUv)
{
    postProcessFlags |= PostProcessSteps.FlipUVs;
}

var model = importer.ImportFile(filename, postProcessFlags);
```

Флаги всего лишь для примера, используйте те параметры, которые Вам нужны.